# Find document with the biggest number of matches (and less number of unmatched) in an array

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Considering I have the following documents (excluding the `_id`):

```
[
  {
    "array": [
      1,
      2,
      3,
      4
    ],
    "string": "doc1"
  },
  {
    "array": [
      3,
      4,
      5
    ],
    "string": "doc2"
  }
]
```

I want to find the document that has the most common elements in “array” compared to `[2,3,4]`. The returned document should be:

```
{
    "array": [
      1,
      2,
      3,
      4
    ],
    "string": "doc1"
}
```

(3 matches)

However if the search is `[3,4,6]` the returned document should be:

```
{
    "array": [
      3,
      4,
      5
    ],
    "string": "doc2"
  }
```

Because both share the same number of matches (2) but the returned document has less elements that don’t match (1 element compared to 2 elements on the other document).

How can I accomplish a query that finds the “best” intersection of the query array with document’s ones?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [$setIntersection](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setIntersection/index.html) operator to calculate a new array and the filter by it's size along with the size of `array`:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $addFields: {
            size: { $size: "$array" },
            intersectionSize: { $size: { $setIntersection: [ [2,3,4], "$array" ] } }
        }
    },
    {
        $sort: {
            intersectionSize: -1,
            size: 1
        }
    },
    {
        $limit: 1
    },
    {
        $project: {
            size: 0,
            intersectionSize: 0
        }
    }
])
```

[Mongo Playground (1)](https://mongoplayground.net/p/JukWaOiQJeu)

[Mongo Playground (2)](https://mongoplayground.net/p/oQlHT-fRemH)

EDIT: sort by size ascending is needed because if there's the same number of matching elements the shorter array will be promoted